# Call Jquery function in @Html.Pager click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using  MvcPaging for pagination in MVC4.
`@Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount)`

I need to call jquery function when click on page no(1,2,3...pagecount).

Not any action or controls, i need to call jquery function.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently done this in my current project.

Simply wrap the
    @Html.Pager
in a div (or some other html container) with a class like that for example:

```
<div class="pager">
    @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount)
</div>
```

You can then easily hook your pager link clicks like this:

```
$(".pager a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your js code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you use on the server doesn't really matter to `jQuery`, you need to attach a clickhandler to the pagination links

```
$('.linksclass').on('click', functiontocall);
```

remember to `return false` on the called function to avoid the default link behaviour (moving to linked page)

Comment: its @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount) generating 1,2,3..pagecount in dynamically from this function.No link button.I need the model.pagenumber as argument

Comment: in the end it just generates html `a` tags! jQuery works on the html and is blind to what generated it! if you have `<div class="pager"><%= Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount) %></div>` the jQuery selector will be `$('.pager a').on('click', functiontocall);`

Comment: ok.But i need current pagenumber(Model.PageNumber).Its in razor view. Click function should fire,that understand.But i need the pageno,In jquery funtion.

Comment: I really don't know much about ASP, but you should be able to get the current page with jQuery because its link will be highlighted with a class I guess `$('.pager a.current').index()+1`